Wondering why I'm getting a syntax error in the last un-indented print function
I was following along a course's example and the last print function was giving an error. Using Python3
x = 4
if x > 2:
    print('Bigger')
else:
    print('Smaller')
print('All done')

Which then follows this error:
File "<stdin>", line 5
    print('All done')
    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Wondering what went wrong, is the course just using a loose example?
I thought it would print both statements

Are you on the REPL (interactive mode)? Then you have to close an indented block with an extra newline (until ... becomes >>>).

Thank you for your response. I'm new to Python so I'm not aware of how to differentiate from interactive mode.
When I'm in the command prompt after opening with py and running the above code again, I tried following your advice and after the 2nd nested print statement the '...' remains even though I thought backspacing would change it

Are you using the Interactive mode?
Try to hit an enter before the last print
>>> x = 4
>>> if x > 2:
...    print('Bigger')
... else:
...    print('Smaller')
...
Bigger
>>> print('All done')
All done

The primary prompt (>>>) is for the next command, while the secondary prompt (...) waits for continuation lines.

I understand now, I had thought based on how it was displayed on the course that  the 3rd print line would be 'grouped together' (I also erroneously thought shift+enter was used to go to the next line without print function activating lol). Now I see that your example is how it's supposed to look like, I appreciate it
